# How do I calculate the answer of a exponential formula?

Tags: php

we have to make a web game for a school project.

but im currently stuck at one point. its a mafia styled web game, you probably know one of these. When your charachter goes to the hospital to get his wounds fixed up he needs to pay a certain amount of money. this is calculated by the following code

```
 $maxHeal = 100 - $health;
 $costs =round(pow($maxHeal,1.8));
```

health is a number between 0 and 100 and the costs are based on exponential growth. but if the player can only afford 50 but types in 100, how do I make sure he only getw 50, and how do I make sure it are the first 50 health points, the most expensive ones and not the cheap ones, this will cause player to just type in 1 press enter to get some cheap health.

I hope my porblem is clear, if you have any questions about other parts of the codes please ask

thanks in advance

edit: to give some extra clearance,

when I am at 10 health(hp) and I want to go back to 100hp I need to get a 90 extra. there is a form where I can type how much hp I want to cure, so I type in 90 and the system requests to ad 90 to my life so it makes 100. to do this I need to check if the players can afford to pay for those 90 points. if I can not pay for 90 but can pay for 50 I want those 50 to be added anyways. but if I count from 1 to 50 and to one form 40(the remaining I need to heal another timer) it wil cost less than counting from 1 to 90 because of the exponential growth.

so I need 2 checks. I have to cure al I can afford, so if I can afford just 50 of the 90 hp I need, I will only get 50 points and pay for 50, but as this wil be cheaper how can I make sure that I pay for the 50 like I woulld pay for 90. so 50 and 40 need to be equal to one times 90

Comment: whats not clear about my problem? could you be more specific please? i tried a lot, dont remember everything i tried...

Comment: What you are looking for? seems like you need logic not code.

Comment: i am looking for a solution, i dont see it ATM, so if anyone could help with logic or with code it would be a big help

Comment: if you need a logic part then your problem statement is not enough to understand. How you are saying afford 50 and where he types 100 and what is first 50 health points??

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question (which is not totally clear to me, but hey, I'm in a good mood), I built the following example:

```
//total amount of health points
$points = 20000;

//health left
$health = 10;

//how many health do we miss? 100 = maximal
$maxHeal = 100 - $health;

//counter
$i = 0;

while($points > $cost = round(pow($maxHeal-$i,1.8))) {

    //check if the user has enough points
    if ($points - $cost > 0) {
        $health++;
        echo "Healt +1 point, total: " . $health . "  (points " . $points . " - cost " . $cost . " = " . ($points - $cost) . " left)" . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Can't heal anymore, not enough points left (" . $points . ")" . "\n";
    }

    $points -= $cost;
    $i++;
}

echo "\n";
echo "Remaining points: " . $points . ", needs points for next repair: " . $cost;
```

With the following output:

```
Health now: 10
Healt +1 point, total: 11  (points 20000 - cost 3293 = 16707 left)
Healt +1 point, total: 12  (points 16707 - cost 3228 = 13479 left)
Healt +1 point, total: 13  (points 13479 - cost 3163 = 10316 left)
Healt +1 point, total: 14  (points 10316 - cost 3098 = 7218 left)
Healt +1 point, total: 15  (points 7218 - cost 3035 = 4183 left)
Healt +1 point, total: 16  (points 4183 - cost 2971 = 1212 left)

Remaining points: 1212, needs points for next repair: 2909
```

I hope this gets you going :)

Comment: one more question benz, my friend, made a while loop which was:while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result). $result is a random query but how can you define a variable in a while loop, wouldnt this cause an unending loop?the query was:select * form users order by xp desc

Comment: @user3133403 In this case "while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))", the $result is a mysql_result resource. The mysql result returns false when there are no more records left (and the while query will break, because $row turns info false. The following is wrong, but will give you a unending loop "while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql)))", the query will be executed every time the while loop asks for it (and false will never be returned (muhahahah)).